# Visual Studio 2017 and Chrome: ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY when starting a fresh new project

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I just downloaded VS 2017 and installed it on Windows 10 Professional. Then, full of hope, I started a new web project with the Angular template. I hit `<Run>`, accepted to install the generated certificate that VS generates for everything to work, and suddenly Chrome said:

`ERR_SPDY_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY`

And now I'm sad and disappointed.

Everyone on internet says that it was fixed with the latest update of VS 2017, but it's not true because I have it totally updated (I just installed it an hour ago, downloaded from Microsoft web page).

I'm running (64bit all of them):

```
Visual Studio Professional 2017, 15.9.7    
Windows 10 Pro, 1709, compilation 16299.402
Chrome 72.0.3626.119
```

Comment: My blog post is clearly irrelevant, as I didn’t write about this specific error message there.

Comment: @LexLi It's the post people suggest from the MSDN. Nevermind, link deleted :).

Comment: I wonder why the negative vote, isn't it a valid question?

Comment: probably because other browsers are free of such issues, and you should go to Chrome documentation or SuperUser to learn how to configure Chrome.

Comment: @LexLi It's ok, I have solved it. See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem adding these two entries into the Windows Registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters]
“EnableHttp2Tls”=dword:00000000
“EnableHttp2Cleartext”=dword:00000000
```

I have found the solution [here](https://www.tecklyfe.com/how-to-fix-ns_error_net_inadequate_security-and-err_spdy_inadequate_transport_security-in-iis-on-windows-server-2016/). It says:

> There are a few reasons for this and the main one is that IIS in Windows Server 2016 turns on HTTP/2 by default and only falls back to the older HTTP/1.1 if the browser doesn’t support HTTP/2. While HTTP/2 is generally a good thing and most recent browser support it, it also has stricter requirements than HTTP/1.1 and the issue with these browser errors is that the Windows Server 2016 is trying to establish an HTTP/2 session with the browser but the server is configured with some weaker SSL Ciphers which aren’t supported by HTTP/2.

Hope it helps others.